# Visual Studio 2017 - how to view a call stack based on dmp file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, crash-dumps

I have a dmp file from the C++ application which crashed on the other machine. I also have an access to the code repository and I know which version of the dll crashes. I open the dmp file in Visual Studio 2017. There are the following actions:

- Debug with Native Only
- Set symbol paths
- Copy all to clipboard

I have built the dll, set symbol paths to the build directory and then I have selected `Debug with Native Only` action. Next I have set `New path` to the build directory but I have got an information that required library is not found.
What I should do to view a crash call stack ? How to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

There could be one or multiple stacks in the memory dump depending on the fact if crashed process was using multiple threads. So having started debug session on the dump you can invoke *Debug/Windows/Parallel Stack* menu commandand see all the stacks ecorded in the memory dump. You can view single stack via *Debug/Windows/Call Stack* menu command.

Comment: Do you have to attach to an .exe first?  I don't see the Parallel option in VS 2019?